# Kafka Broker throws error for clients that produce snappy compressed messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I just finished my Kafka cluster setup using Confluent Platform 6.0.0 (Apache Kafka version 2.6.0). The Kafka brokers are deployed in Kubernetes. Producing messages to a new topic works fine as long as it's not compressed.

However I just tried to produce a snappy compressed message and got an error returned. Hence I looked at the broker logs and saw the following exception in the broker:

```
[2020-11-24 13:14:37,834] ERROR (data-plane-kafka-request-handler-0:Logging) [ReplicaManager broker=1] Error processing append operation on partition customers-2
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.CompressionType$3.wrapForInput(CompressionType.java:92)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch.compressedIterator(DefaultRecordBatch.java:261)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch.skipKeyValueIterator(DefaultRecordBatch.java:340)
        at kafka.log.LogValidator$.$anonfun$validateMessagesAndAssignOffsetsCompressed$1(LogValidator.scala:401)
        at kafka.log.LogValidator$.$anonfun$validateMessagesAndAssignOffsetsCompressed$1$adapted(LogValidator.scala:394)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:920)
        at kafka.log.LogValidator$.validateMessagesAndAssignOffsetsCompressed(LogValidator.scala:394)
        at kafka.log.LogValidator$.validateMessagesAndAssignOffsets(LogValidator.scala:106)
        at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$append$2(Log.scala:1095)
        at kafka.log.Log.append(Log.scala:2340)
        at kafka.log.Log.appendAsLeader(Log.scala:1019)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$appendRecordsToLeader$1(Partition.scala:984)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.appendRecordsToLeader(Partition.scala:972)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.$anonfun$appendToLocalLog$4(ReplicaManager.scala:883)
        at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedMapOps.map(StrictOptimizedMapOps.scala:28)
        at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedMapOps.map$(StrictOptimizedMapOps.scala:27)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.map(HashMap.scala:34)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.appendToLocalLog(ReplicaManager.scala:871)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.appendRecords(ReplicaManager.scala:571)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleProduceRequest(KafkaApis.scala:605)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:132)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:70)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.readFully(SnappyInputStream.java:145)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.readHeader(SnappyInputStream.java:99)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.<init>(SnappyInputStream.java:59)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.CompressionType$3.wrapForInput(CompressionType.java:90)
        ... 24 more
```

Additional info: In Kubernetes I configured that the container has no permissions to write files to the local filesystem. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but maybe this is required for the snappy class to be initialized successfully?

Why does Kafka fail to handle snappy compressed messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this in two different ways:

1. Set env-var `KAFKA_OPTS='-Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/some/other/path/with/exec/permissions'`. This will be picked-up by `kafka-run-class.sh` (& `kafka-server-start`) so that your broker unpack the library to a suitable filesystem with exec permissions.
2. Rebuild your docker image so that you mount the /tmp with exec permissions (`mount -o remount,exec /tmp`)

The problem is explained here:

1. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8622
2. https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-trblshoot/doc/troubleshooting/snappytrbl.html

Answer (score 2):

As already assumed this is actually caused by lacking permissions for the root file system. The snappy producer apparently requires write access to `/tmp`. I mounted an `emptyDir` volume to this path and now it works as expected.